# Using a local copy of bootstrap to render webpages in django

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, django-bootstrap3

I have `django` webserver. I use `bootstrap` in my `html` pages. This was how I had included it and was working fine,

```
    {% load static %}
    <script src="{% static 'jquery/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

But I want to use a local copy of bootstrap. So I made the following changes after downloading bootstrap from this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) (the zip file included three directories `css`, `fonts` and `js` which I copied into `django`'s static directory).

```
    {% load static %}
    <script src="{% static 'jquery/jquery.min.js'%}"></script>

    {% load static %}
    <link rel="script" type="text/javascript" href="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js'%}">

    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css'%}">
```

Everything seems to work fine. But when I try to show `bootstrap modals` which are a part of my webpage, I get the following error,

```
    Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
        at zoomIn ((index):76)
        at HTMLImageElement.onclick ((index):1)
```

Am I not downloading the correct version of bootstrap? What is it I am doing wrong?

Comment: How the resulting HTML code looks?

Comment: The bootstrap is working fine even in the resulting html. Only the `.modal() ` function gives an error. The other bootstrap parts works fine.

Comment: It seems like version conflict. You got latest version of bootstrap which is 3.3.7. Its requirement for jQuery version described here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.7/bower.json  - jQuery has to be not less than 1.9.1 - 3

Comment: My current version of jquery is 1.9.1.. but i tried with versions 3.1.1 and 1.11.3... Both don't seem to work